# How to use python "login shell" with "call"?

Tags: python, shell, call, subprocess

I am trying to use python to call environmentally defined functions on a large computer cluster.

These fail due the difference between a login shell and a non-login shell, as I understand it (i.e., different init scripts are run).
Although I could try to use the aliased functions directly (although initial tries don't work for my particular case), I would prefer to just generically load the necessary files to have a "login shell" be the one used in python's call function.

I tried something like:

```
call("sh /etc/profile;sh $HOME/.bash_profile; MY COMMAND", shell=True )
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: it doesn't work because you are running `/etc/profile` in a subprocess (`sh`), that closes before the next command starts. Using `source` (http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) let you have the command run in the same process `MY COMMAND` will run.

Answer (score 2):

profile files should be read by `.` or `source` command.

Executing profile files with `sh` cause sub-shell to execute the files. Setting environment variables of the sub-shell does not affect the parent shell.

```
call(". /etc/profile;. $HOME/.bash_profile; MY COMMAND", shell=True )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force a login shell with a command line

```
-sh -c "MY COMMAND"
```

Prefixing the shell name with `-` invokes it as a login shell, rather than an ordinary shell.